# is declaring variables in between code bad practice?

Tags: c++, declaration, local-variables

I realize this might be a controversial topic, but as a prospective developer who is entering industry in a couple of weeks, I'm trying to get an idea of the do's and dont's when writing code.

One of the things that even my professors seem to be at odds on is where should local variables be declared. I've had professors insist that the only way is to declare them all at the start of the function. This has the benefit of not reconstructing a new object every time a loop is entered, for example. But it has the draw back of making logic harder to follow since you don't know which variables are used in which scopes.

Other professors say that it is good practice to declare them when you use them. Even if it's in the middle of the lines of code. This seems to be more of a Python style of coding and could possibly clutter the code with, verbose, and unnecessary type information. Also, this could incur a performance penalty since the object will get constructed and then destructed in every iteration of the loop.

Then I had another professor say to declare them at the start of their respective scopes. So ideally, after each `{` there would be declarations for all the variables used in that scope. This seems to offer the best readability, and the worst performance since now the object could potentially be constructed and then assigned to (two separate, possibly expensive operations) in every loop iteration.

I hope you can see how a new programmer can get confused about what format to follow. So is there consensus in the work field about which style is the "best"?

Comment: "*This seems to be more of a Python style of coding*" C++ was doing it *long* before Python. "*unnecessary type information*" That's what `auto` is for. "*this could incur a performance penalty since the object will get constructed and then destructed in every iteration of the loop*" Then put that object before the loop. Why does everything have to be all or nothing?

Comment: The simple answer is to follow whatever guidelines and coding style your employer uses.

Comment: My personal opinion is that if you have more than one or two scopes in your function, break it down to several functions.

Comment: Interesting question but unfortunately too opinion-based for this forum.

Comment: "Interesting question but unfortunately too opinion-based for this forum." I thought so. Still had to try to see if there is a one agreed upon style

Comment: Short answer: do whatever your team does. Most, but not all, C++ code I’ve seen tries to declare variables as close as possible to where they’re used. This is also the style recommended by the very highly regarded book Code Complete 2.

Comment: "declare them all at the start of the function. " - this was due to limitations of 1970s compilers, it's not relevant today

Comment: `This has the benefit of not reconstructing a new object every time a loop is entered` a smart compiler will not modify the stack frame just because a new variable has been declared. Check any modern compiler's output and you'll see

Comment: If constructing some object is expensive, then yes, move it out of a loop scope. But for trivial examples, an optimizing compiler can often figure out that the variable doesn’t change in between loop iterations and move it out for you.

Comment: On the other hand, if you have an expansive to construct object that's needed in a single branch, you just pessimized the whole function by *always* constructing it at the top.

Comment: @phuclv in c++, the compiler may not be able to tell whether construction/destruction of an object has side effects, if its constructor and destructor are defined in another translation unit. So it might not be able to move them out of loops.

Comment: How expensive does a construction need to be to get pushed outside the loop? Will a vector that is used to get some return value from some function be considered something that should be moved out of a loop?

Comment: "So is there consensus in the work field about which style is the "best"?" No.

Comment: @GamefanA in general it depends on how performance-sensitive what you're doing is.

If you're working on tight numeric loops where every cycle matters then something as small as an extra allocation in the loop would definitely kill performance. If you're working on something more generic then constructing an empty vector in a loop probably doesn't matter. But no matter what you're working on, you should at the bare minimum try to avoid doing any sort of unnecessary disk or network access. It'd be a bit weird though if any constructors did that, but not impossible...